# Microsoft IIS converting https url to http

Tags: iis, iis-6, weblogic

I am newbie to Microsoft IIS.

I've Microsoft IIS web server acting as reverse proxy for WebLogic application server, https is enabled on both the servers.

I am running into this issue of Microsoft IIS is converting https to http. I found this post which explains this -
http://geekexplains.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/https-becoming-http-in-case-of.html

Is there any configuration or something I can do in Microsoft IIS not to convert urls? Please suggest.

I've IIS on Windows 2003 server.

Thanks.